# graphviz dot: how to insert arrows from a node to center of an arrow

Tags: graphviz, dot

I try to create diagrams for MPLUS analyses with dot from the graphviz package. Does anybody have experience with using dot to visualize structural equation models/latent class mixture models? There is especially one feature that I can't figure out how to do beautifully:

I need arrows from nodes to the center of another arrow like

> ```
>            C
>            |
>            |
>            V
>    A ------------> B
> ```

I tried to insert an invisible node at the intersection of the arrows. This, however,  results in a "cracked" A--->B arrow because dot does represent it as two independent arrows.
Is this even possible with dot?

Thanks for suggestions and help!

Gregor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Building on spenthil's answer to get rid of the kink:

```
digraph {
  ab[label="", fixedsize="false", width=0, height=0, shape=none];

  a -> ab[arrowhead=None];
  ab -> b;
  c -> ab;

  {rank=same; a; ab; b};
}
```

Output:

[image: graphviz output]

An other possibility would be to play with the `weight` attribute of the edges to straighten out edges.

Answer (score 6):

The following prevents "cracked" arrows. Dot unfortunately introduces a kink between the `a -> ab` and `ab->b` edges. Not aware of a layout algorithm that prevents this.

```
digraph {
  a;
  ab[label="", fixedsize="false", width=0, height=0, shape=none];
  b;
  c;

  a -> ab[arrowhead=None];
  ab -> b;
  c -> ab;
}
```

Output:

[image]