# How can I permit overlapping edges in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot, edges, orthogonal

### Background

I'm using Graphviz to create an Organizational Chart.

### Problem

By default `dot` creates the following diagram:

[image: Default Output]

The desired output combines the edges so that they overlap, with elbow connections:

[image: Desired Output]

### Source Code

The following source code generates the problematic diagram:

```
digraph G {
  splines = ortho;
  concentrate = true;

  node [shape="box", style="rounded", penwidth = 2];
  edge [color="#142b30", arrowhead="vee", penwidth = 2];

  {
    rank = same
    "1";
    "2";
    "3";
    "4";
  }

  "Main Node" -> "1";
  "Main Node" -> "2";
  "Main Node" -> "3";
  "Main Node" -> "4";

  {
    rank = same
    "5";
    "6";
    "7";
  }

  "1" -> "5";
  "1" -> "6";
  "1" -> "7";
}
```

### Question

How can `dot` create orthogonal, elbow-joint edges in a Manhattan layout?

### Ideas

I have tried various combinations of `sametail` and `tailport` to no avail.

Comment: Similar to @marapet's answer, you can take inspiration from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718025/graphviz-dot-how-to-insert-arrows-from-a-node-to-center-of-an-arrow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating "elbow-joint" edges is only possible by inserting invisible ("dummy") nodes.

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675212/59087) to a similar question for details.